# Global log level for CocoaLumberjack

Tags: ios, objective-c, logging, cocoalumberjack

I'm using [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack) in an iPhone project, to log some information.

I've followed [the Getting started guide](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/GettingStarted), and everything works fine, but there is one thing that bugs me: there doesn't seem to be an elegant way to define a log level for the whole app. To make it work I need to define a constant in every source file, like this:

```
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

So, is there a way to define a global log level for the application?

I found [this article](http://bluedogtech.blogspot.com/2010/12/global-log-level-control-with.html) on the subject, but I still need to add an #import in every file...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I didn't find a better way to do it than the one explained in [the article](http://bluedogtech.blogspot.com/2010/12/global-log-level-control-with.html) I mentioned in the question.

*Constant.h*

```
extern int const ddLogLevel;
```

*Constant.m*

```
#import "Constants.h"
#import "DDLog.h"

int const ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

*Logger configuration*

```
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "DDASLLogger.h"
#import "DDTTYLogger.h"
#import "DDFileLogger.h"

...

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

 [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
 [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

 DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init]; 
 [DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];
 [fileLogger release];

...
```

*Import your class*

```
#import "DDLog.h"
#import "Constants.h"

...

- (void)someMethod {
 DDLogVerbose(@"Log this message");
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to do dynamic logging with this?

Comment: Please, avoid answers where the only source of information is an external link. At least quote the essential points of the resource, in order to avoid link rotting.

Comment: I see what you're doing  @Marcos Crispino.. but I'm guessing this will only work if the only constant that's defined in `Constants.h` is the logging constant (ie as opposed to having all your global constants in that file).. in that case the name `Constants.h` is misleading, as it is specific to the log level.. i'd call it `GlobalLogLevel.h` or something that more accurately describes and limits the scope of this file

Comment: anyways I kinda created my own [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27902859/766570) based on yours, which adds the benefit of being able to override the global log level on a per file basis

Answer (score 21):

You could use an `#include` statement in your *.pch file so that it's automatically included in all your project's files.

Comment: Also - To customize on a per-file basis, change `ddLogLevel` to non-const, and set it in the specific file's class +initialize method (This works because each .m file gets its own static ddLogLevel variable). Note: Classes may call their superclass's +initialize method, so to avoid potential bugs use `if (self == [ClassName self])`  in the method.

Comment: The problem being is that .pch files are no longer provided in Xcode projects by default. You should probably consider them deprecated.

Answer (score 16):

### No more Prefix Headers, please.

You do not need the now deprecated `.pch` file, simply include a header file where needed.

#### Logger.h - CocoaLumberjack 1.9.x

```
#ifndef Project_Logger_h
#define Project_Logger_h

#if defined(__OBJC__)

#import <CocoaLumberjack/DDLog.h>
extern int ddLogLevel;

#endif

#endif
```

#### Logger.m

```
#import "Logger.h"

int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

#### Changes for CocoaLumberjack 2.x

```
#import <CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack.h>

int ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelVerbose;
```

If the syntax changes when 2.0 is out of beta please comment or edit.

#### Example usage in AppDelegate

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

#import "Logger.h"

#import <CocoaLumberjack/DDFileLogger.h>
#import <CocoaLumberjack/DDASLLogger.h>
#import <CocoaLumberjack/DDTTYLogger.h>



@interface AppDelegate ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) DDFileLogger *fileLogger;
@end



@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
    [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

    DDFileLogger *fileLogger = [[DDFileLogger alloc] init];
    fileLogger.rollingFrequency = 60 * 60 * 24; // 24 hour rolling
    fileLogger.logFileManager.maximumNumberOfLogFiles = 7;

    [DDLog addLogger:fileLogger];
    self.fileLogger = fileLogger;

    DDLogDebug(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DDLogDebug(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DDLogDebug(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DDLogDebug(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DDLogDebug(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    DDLogDebug(@"%s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Comment: In CocoaLumberjack 2.0, the type for the `ddLogLevel` is changed to `DDLogLevel` (https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack). So should it be `extern DDLogLevel ddLogLevel;`

Comment: When exactly was the precompiled header deprecated? This seems a bit misleading. There is nothing wrong with them if they're used correctly.

Comment: They were removed from project defaults in Xcode 6 for good reason. I believe at the time Chris Lattner even mentioned the at WWDC that year as a bad idea that needed to go

Comment: @Greg so in summary, as has been written elsewhere, PCH was an overused crutch, there is no need for them and Apple removed them from default projects to discourage/end their use. Modules resolved the one legitimate use case, importing Foundation.  In the end, you can always establish a global header, but then you're in the business of globals. While you're at it, you can stuff significant amounts of code in AppDelegate.

Answer (score 5):

You can use this in your *.pch file to automatically get different global log levels depending upon your current build configuration.[for xcode 4+]

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
#else
  static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_WARN;
#endif
```

or If you need a different log level for every logger, you can easily achieve this using the DDLog +addLogger:withLogLevel: method.

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance] withLogLevel:LOG_LEVEL_INFO];
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] withLogLevel:LOG_LEVEL_DEBUG];
```

Defining a log level in every source file you mentioned has a benefit. You can use verbose logging level just for the part that you're currently working on. For rest part, you can use other level like info, warn, error.

Comment: .pch should not be used, they are deprecated

Answer (score 5):

In order to dynamically inject log level (for example, from configuration file):

1) Create a new class named DDLogLevel with the following code:

```
#import "DDLogLevel.h"
#import "DDLog.h"

@implementation DDLogLevel

static int _ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;

+ (int)ddLogLevel
{
    return _ddLogLevel;
}

+ (void)ddSetLogLevel:(int)logLevel
{
    _ddLogLevel = logLevel;
}

@end
```

2) In DDLogLevel.h, find the row that contains the following statement:

```
#ifndef LOG_LEVEL_DEF
    #define LOG_LEVEL_DEF ddLogLevel
#endif
```

And replace it with:

```
#ifndef LOG_LEVEL_DEF
    #define LOG_LEVEL_DEF [DDLogLevel ddLogLevel]
#endif
```

3) Finally, call from your Initialization process (perhaps from appDelegate) to ddSetLogLevel with the desired level.

Answer (score 5):

For those using CocoaLumberjackSwift you can simply set the following global variable anywhere in your code:

```
dynamicLogLevel = .verbose
```

[Discussion here](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/1096#issuecomment-533967562)

Answer (score 3):

Share my configuration for CocoaLumberjack 2.0.0 with `global log level` and optional `local log level` with preserved [DynamicLogLevels feature](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/DynamicLogLevels.md).

My solution includes simple header file `DSLogging.h` (and it's counterpart) that import `CocoaLumberjack.h` and define convenience macros for setting up the files that use CocoaLumberjack log macros. Here is how you should use it:

1. Import `DSLogging.h` header (two ways):

   - Import it in each file that uses CocoaLumberjack. [Just as native framework documentation propose](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md).
   - Import it in `.pch` file once. **[Consider this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24194968/991816) before going this way.**
2. Use `DSLogLevelSetup...` macros to set log level for file. Note: there should be macros in EACH source file that uses logging.

See documentation inside for more details. [Download gist](https://gist.github.com/DanSkeel/9631d0b8b55cce8bd5a8).

### `DSLogging.h` header:

```
//
//  Created by DanSkeel on 23.04.15.

#import "CocoaLumberjack.h"

#define DS_LogScopeGlobal extern
#define DS_LogScopeLocal static
#define DS_LogMutableYes
#define DS_LogMutableNo const

#define DS_LogValueGlobal ;
#define DS_LogValueLocal(lvl) = lvl

#define DS_Setup_Log(scope, mutablility, value) scope mutablility DDLogLevel ddLogLevel value

/** To setup loggin enviroment for particular file use one of these macros
 *
 *  @note Use CocoaLumberjack as usual (https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/blob/master/Documentation/GettingStarted.md):
 *
 *  1. just import DSLoggin.h in source file instead of CocoaLumberjack.h
 *
 *  2. Use one of these macros to setup loggin enviroment for the file.
 *  Note: there should one of these macros in EACH file that uses CocoaLumberjack macroses.
 *  @example To enable logging for file with globally defined level you can make convinient snippet:
 *  @code
 *  #import "DSLogging.h"
 *  DSLogLevelSetupGlobal
 *  @endcode
 * 
 *  Use @b SetupGlobal to setup files that will use global level from @p DSLogging.m file
 *
 *  Use @b SetupMutableGlobal to be able to change global level at runtime (assign new level to ddLogLevel variable)
 *
 *  Use @b Setup(DDLogLevel) to set local log level
 *
 *  Use @b SetupMutable(DDLogLevel) to be able to modify local level at runtime ((assign new level to ddLogLevel variable))
 *
 *  This approach preserves a lot of CocoaLumberjack advantages. See SO https://stackoverflow.com/a/29837945/991816
 *
 *  @remarks details: these macros just help you define/reference ddLogLevel value. So if you
 *  see warning about <i> undeclared identifier </i> it should remind you to use one of these macros in this file.
 */
extern char optionClickMeToSeePrettyDoc;
#define DSLogLevelSetupMutableGlobal DS_Setup_Log(DS_LogScopeGlobal, DS_LogMutableYes, DS_LogValueGlobal)
#define DSLogLevelSetupGlobal        DS_Setup_Log(DS_LogScopeGlobal, DS_LogMutableNo,  DS_LogValueGlobal)
#define DSLogLevelSetupMutable(lvl)  DS_Setup_Log(DS_LogScopeLocal,  DS_LogMutableYes, DS_LogValueLocal(lvl))
#define DSLogLevelSetup(lvl)         DS_Setup_Log(DS_LogScopeLocal,  DS_LogMutableNo,  DS_LogValueLocal(lvl))
```

### `DSLogging.m` source:

```
//
//  Created by DanSkeel on 23.04.15.

#import "DSLogging.h"

DDLogLevel ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelVerbose;
```

### Why I think it's a good approach:

1. It's a little better than just CocoaLumberjack

   - Global level (can be mutable)
   - Allows you to "override" global level by local level (can be mutable)
2. It doesn't cut CocoaLumberjack functions

   - Uses variable to set level, so it can be used with advanced features of CocoaLumberjack.

<sub>I'm new to CocoaLumberjack and I can be too optimistic about my approach, would be glad to hear your critics if I lie at some point.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

As answered by FreeAsInBeer, you can define this constant in .pch file. You may do like this in .pch file.

```
// include Lumberjack header file 
#import <Lumberjack/Lumberjack.h>

// define ddLogLevel constant
static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;
```

Im my implement, I create a new header file(e.g. mylog.h) for custom Lumberjack settings. in this way, I use `#import` statement in my .pch file for including mylog.h. This custom header file may like this.

```
// include Lumberjack header file
#import "Lumberjack.h" 

#undef ZEKit_LOG_LEVEL
#if defined (DEBUG) && (DEBUG == 1)
#define ZEKit_LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE
#else
#define ZEKit_LOG_LEVEL LOG_LEVEL_WARN
#endif

static const int ddLogLevel = ZEKit_LOG_LEVEL;

// ... Other custom settings
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5218761/766570) answer.. however This is how I did it differently so that I can have both a global level log level **and** be able to override the global log level within each file if I so chose:

- Instead of calling the file `Constants.h` I called it `GlobalDebugLevel.h`. This is because it doesn't make sense to include any other global constants in this file, unless you really will *always* use the global debug level and have no use for file specific log levels.
- In the files that I want to have it's own log level.. I simply comment out the `#import "GlobalLogLevel.h" and then include something like this:

`static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;`

and everybody is happy :)

p.s. this is a `.pch` free solution.. inititally I tried that but then the compiler would complain that `ddLogLevel` is already defined whenever I wanted to override it at a file level

Answer (score 0):

There is a much easier way to solve this, you can set the log level at the Logger instantiation:

```
#ifdef DEBUG
  [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] withLevel:DDLogLevelDebug];
#else
  [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance] withLevel:DDLogLevelError];
#endif
```

So there is no need for extra imports or .pch-file.

Comment: But still you will have this error:
    DDLogInfo(@"test info"); -> Use of undeclared identifier 'ddLogLevel'

Comment: This works with Version 2.0.0, the update to 2.0.1 breaks this solution. This is discussed here: https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/issues/542

Answer (score 0):

Here is a dynamic logging example, which uses DanSkeels DSLogging code from below:

GFDPerson.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface GFDPerson : NSObject{
@protected
    NSArray         *pLogLevelNames;
    NSArray         *pLogLevelKeys;
    NSDictionary    *pLogLevels;
}

-(void)logPerson;
-(void)setLogLevel:(NSUInteger)logLevel;

@end
```

GFDPerson.m

```
#import "GFDPerson.h"
#import "DSLogging.h"

DSLogLevelSetupMutable(DDLogLevelWarning);

@implementation GFDPerson

-(id)init{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        pLogLevelNames = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                          @"no logging",
                          @"only errors",
                          @"errors and warnings",
                          @"errors, warnings and infos",
                          @"verbose",
                          nil];

        pLogLevelKeys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                         [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:DDLogLevelOff]stringValue],
                         [[NSNumber     numberWithInteger:DDLogLevelError]stringValue],
                         [[NSNumber     numberWithInteger:DDLogLevelWarning]stringValue],
                         [[NSNumber     numberWithInteger:DDLogLevelInfo]stringValue],
                         [[NSNumber     numberWithInteger:DDLogLevelVerbose]stringValue],
                         nil];

        pLogLevels = [[NSDictionary alloc]initWithObjects:pLogLevelNames
                                                  forKeys:pLogLevelKeys];

        return self;
    }
    return nil;
}

-(void)setLogLevel:(NSUInteger)logLevel{
    ddLogLevel = logLevel;
}

-(void)logPerson{

    NSLog(@"Person is logging with Loglevel: %@",[pLogLevels valueForKey:    [[NSNumber numberWithInteger:ddLogLevel]stringValue]]);
    DDLogVerbose(@"Person log verbose");
    DDLogInfo(@"Person log info");
    DDLogWarn(@"Person log warning");
    DDLogError(@"Person log error");
    DDLogDebug(@"Person log debug");
}

@end
```

main.m

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "DSLogging.h"
#import "GFDPerson.h"

DSLogLevelSetupMutable(DDLogLevelError);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        [DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
        [DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];

        ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelWarning;
        NSLog(@"Warning:");
        DDLogWarn(@"WARNING LOG!");
        DDLogError(@"ERROR LOG!");
        DDLogVerbose(@"VERBOSE LOG!");

        ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelError;
        NSLog(@"Error:");
        DDLogWarn(@"WARNING LOG!");
        DDLogError(@"ERROR LOG!");
        DDLogVerbose(@"VERBOSE LOG!");

        ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelOff;
        NSLog(@"Off:");
        DDLogWarn(@"WARNING LOG!");
        DDLogError(@"ERROR LOG!");
        DDLogVerbose(@"VERBOSE LOG!");

        ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelVerbose;
        NSLog(@"Verbose:");
        DDLogWarn(@"WARNING LOG!");
        DDLogError(@"ERROR LOG!");
        DDLogVerbose(@"VERBOSE LOG!");

        ddLogLevel = DDLogLevelOff;
        GFDPerson *personA = [[GFDPerson alloc] init];
        [personA logPerson];

        [personA setLogLevel:DDLogLevelVerbose];
        [personA logPerson];

        [personA setLogLevel:DDLogLevelError];
        [personA logPerson];

    }
    return 0;
}
```

output of this code:

```
Warning:
WARNING LOG!
ERROR LOG!
Error:
ERROR LOG!
Off:
Verbose:
WARNING LOG!
ERROR LOG!
VERBOSE LOG!
Person is logging with Loglevel: errors and warnings
Person log warning
Person log error
Person is logging with Loglevel: verbose
Person log verbose
Person log info
Person log warning
Person log error
Person log debug
Person is logging with Loglevel: only errors
Person log error
```

Please comment, If I misunderstood or misused something...

Answer (score -2):

There's an example app included with CocoaLumberjack that shows how to set a global log level that you can find here https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/tree/master/Xcode/GlobalLogLevel

Comment: Please, avoid answers where the only source of information is an external link. At least quote the essential points of the resource, in order to avoid link rotting.