# How to view DDLogVerbose() in console

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoa

I'm ensuring an API works correctly with a mobile app I have running in xcode.  There are `DDLogVerbose()` calls throughout the application that I'm not able to see the output of in the console.  Is there something I need to do before I can view that?

I did not configure xcode, I just cloned a git repo and hit the "Play" icon in the top left corner to build and run the project.

Right now I'm seeing a very generic error, and viewing these detailed logs would make it MUCH easier for me to debug this iteration that's failing...

**Update**

DDLogVerbose is part of [CocoaLumberjack](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/GettingStarted).  The instructions there for installation don't indicate anything about how to build/run the application.

Comment: Please provide a link to `DDLogVerbose()`.

Comment: @trojanfoe I've posted a link to the project where this method is coming from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the log level.

According to the [README](https://github.com/CocoaLumberjack/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/GettingStarted), you need something like this:

```
#import "Sprocket.h"
#import "DDLog.h"

static const int ddLogLevel = LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE;

@implementation Sprocket

- (void)someMethod
{
    DDLogVerbose(@"Meet George Jetson");
}
```

[This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118053/global-log-level-for-cocoalumberjack) provides a method of setting this level globally, throughout your app.

Additionally, if you use a `[DDLog addLogger:someLogger withLevel:DDLogLevelVerbose];` without setting the global `ddLogLevel`, you won't get you logs outputted. So your best bet is to always set `ddLogLevel` to `LOG_LEVEL_VERBOSE` (or `DDLogLevelVerbose` in the newer versions of CocoaLumberjack) and then reducing the log level on the individual loggers.